Issues restoring iPad (Disabled, Error 2015)
Relative died. Another relative trying to make use of their iPad (6th Generation A1893) gave it to me (the family "tech guru") because it wants a passcode and he never wrote them down. They don't care about keeping any content, they just would rather not throw it away.  I plugged it into my computer (running Catalina). The iPad would not appear in Apple Music (1.0.6), or iTunes (10.7, I maintain it because it has depreciated features I like), or in the Finder.
There is nothing indicating it is locked by the Find-My feature.  After some research, I put the iPad into Recovery mode. It appeared in the Finder. I ran the Restore option. After some time, the process was done and the iPad rebooted. Unfortunately, it still wanted a passcode. I tried a random passcode and it now says "iPad is Disabled. Connect to iTunes" (which, as noted, it does not appear in iTunes).
After more research (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6146220), I tried running Update first. Unfortunately, after going through the process, I received the error "The iPad iPad could not be restored. An unknown error occurred (2015)." I've done more looking, and all paths seemed to lead to https://support.apple.com/en-us/118106. However, I've already done all of these steps.
So what do I do if I get the 2015 error while following the instructions for the 2015 error?
Additionally, if this IS locked by Find-My, would they have to go through his iCloud account to unlock it since it no longer offers passcode entry?  (If so, why does it insist I connect it to iTunes which offers no such entry?)

The last step in the KB you listed is contact Apple support. They can walk you through resetting it to determine if it’s locked to an Apple ID. All iOS devices need to contact Apple to validate the OS is signed during activation, so that’s all normal. Same with the old iPadOS not knowing about finder or music. Ignore the iTunes error as expected and focus on taking it to a computer that gets a different error or making sure support reviews your steps to be sure one wasn’t missed.

Were they not able to go through Apple for an easier resolution?  You can report the death to Apple and they should be able to assist you with unlocking the device.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/102431
